# java: Retaining value of a text field but clearing it after checking particular condition

Tags: java, jsp

I want to validate an employee form wherein i want that if someone enters first name which is greater than 20 characters then it should clear the field.

```
 First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value=<%=request.getAttribute("fname") != null  ? request.getAttribute("fname"): "" %>>
```

I used this code to retain text field value..but m unable to give a condition to it and assign value..please guide me.

Comment: You need to use javascript.

Comment: Eh, that's JSP, not Java? What validation framework are you using? Clientside or serverside?

Comment: serverside validation..

Comment: that means m validating in servlet

Answer (score 0):

Extend that expression (inside your `<%= … %>`) to the following:

```
request.getAttribute("fname") == null ? "" :
request.getAttribute("fname").length() > 20 ? "" :
request.getAttribute("fname")
```

Each ondition is checked one after the other, until the first one that matches. The corresponding value will be returned. There should be a way to avoid retyping `request.getAttribute("fname")` but the result wouldn't be a single expression any more.

```
<%
  String fname = request.getAttribute("fname");
  if (fname == null || fname.length() > 20) fname = "";
%>
First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="<%= fname %>">
```